# How to Create editable filed in sales > order Grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, grid, delivery

How to create editable delivery date columns in order grid page.

[image]

Please Advice me.How to Create

**`Thanks.`**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add column component in listing.xml as below

```
<column name="date_column_example_2" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
    <settings>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</dateFormat>
        <label translate="true">Date Column Example 2</label>
        <timezone>false</timezone>
        <editor>
            <editorType>date</editorType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </editor>
    </settings>
</column>
```

Comment: i have already tryied. but not success.

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Comment: @MohitPatel can you please also update question with code you have tried.